# how to compare mysql record date and php current date?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to compare two dates, if the dates match then just record but not insert in database and if they are not same data insert in database.

I need it for attendance system to avoid duplicate entry for same time.

Comment: Using mysql date function  you can easily compare date

Comment: What you have tried so far.

Comment: Another idea is to generate strings from the dates and compare these strings ... but Priyanks solution is more solid.

Comment: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date))` with both dates and then compare them

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE date(date_filed) = yourphpdate

Comment: Please paste the code you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your dates are valid date object.

```
  if(strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2)){
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can easily find data using mysql date function.**

```
"SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE date(date_filed) = '".phpdate."'"
```

Answer (score 0):

> It will handle on query.Please check bellow :
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM table where DATE(date)=CURDATE();
> ```